# Data race during nested thread creation

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, valgrind

While trying to create nested threads, helgrind reports several different types of data races.

```
==4429== Possible data race during write of size 8 at 0x5673830 by thread #13
==4429== Locks held: none
==4429==    at 0x4C379EF: memset (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_helgrind-amd64-linux.so)
==4429==    by 0x5060C85: get_cached_stack (allocatestack.c:250)
==4429==    by 0x5060C85: allocate_stack (allocatestack.c:501)
==4429==    by 0x5060C85: pthread_create@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (pthread_create.c:537)
==4429==    by 0x4C32BF7: ??? (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_helgrind-amd64-linux.so)
==4429==    by 0x4022D7: read_group (c_esp.c:318)
==4429==    by 0x4C32DF6: ??? (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_helgrind-amd64-linux.so)
==4429==    by 0x50606A9: start_thread (pthread_create.c:333)
==4429==  Address 0x5673830 is 16 bytes inside a block of size 560 alloc'd
==4429==    at 0x4C2EFB5: calloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_helgrind-amd64-linux.so)
==4429==    by 0x40134C4: allocate_dtv (dl-tls.c:322)
==4429==    by 0x40134C4: _dl_allocate_tls (dl-tls.c:544)
==4429==    by 0x50610D2: allocate_stack (allocatestack.c:588)
==4429==    by 0x50610D2: pthread_create@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (pthread_create.c:537)
==4429==    by 0x4C32BF7: ??? (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_helgrind-amd64-linux.so)
==4429==    by 0x4022D7: read_group (c_esp.c:318)
==4429==    by 0x4C32DF6: ??? (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_helgrind-amd64-linux.so)
==4429==    by 0x50606A9: start_thread (pthread_create.c:333)
==4429==  Block was alloc'd by thread #3


==4429== Possible data race during write of size 1 at 0x724368F by thread #13
==4429== Locks held: none
==4429==    at 0x4C3856C: mempcpy (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_helgrind-amd64-linux.so)
==4429==    by 0x40132F6: _dl_allocate_tls_init (dl-tls.c:520)
==4429==    by 0x5060C8D: get_cached_stack (allocatestack.c:253)
==4429==    by 0x5060C8D: allocate_stack (allocatestack.c:501)
==4429==    by 0x5060C8D: pthread_create@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (pthread_create.c:537)
==4429==    by 0x4C32BF7: ??? (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_helgrind-amd64-linux.so)
==4429==    by 0x4022D7: read_group (c_esp.c:318)
==4429==    by 0x4C32DF6: ??? (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_helgrind-amd64-linux.so)
==4429==    by 0x50606A9: start_thread (pthread_create.c:333)
==4429== 
==4429== This conflicts with a previous write of size 1 by thread #4
==4429== Locks held: none
==4429==    at 0x5060612: start_thread (pthread_create.c:265)
==4429==  Address 0x724368f is in a rw- anonymous segment


==4429== Possible data race during read of size 8 at 0x7243728 by thread #14
==4429== Locks held: none
==4429==    at 0x40178C: read_record (c_esp.c:171)
==4429==    by 0x4C32DF6: ??? (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_helgrind-amd64-linux.so)
==4429==    by 0x50606A9: start_thread (pthread_create.c:333)
==4429== 
==4429== This conflicts with a previous write of size 8 by thread #13
==4429== Locks held: none
==4429==    at 0x5060DB7: pthread_create@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (pthread_create.c:589)
==4429==    by 0x4C32BF7: ??? (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_helgrind-amd64-linux.so)
==4429==    by 0x4022D7: read_group (c_esp.c:318)
==4429==    by 0x4C32DF6: ??? (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_helgrind-amd64-linux.so)
==4429==    by 0x50606A9: start_thread (pthread_create.c:333)
==4429==  Address 0x7243728 is in a rw- anonymous segment
```

The mentioned lines are:

- 318: pthread_create(pth_array + k, &attrs, read_record, args_array +
  k);
- 171: void *read_record(void *_args){

So it seems that there is a data race when threads are being created? Is it possible that the allocated stack for threads in "different branches" is being overlapped? Or did I screw up somewhere?

I already tried reducing stack size for each thread with no success.

As requested, a minimal reproducible example:

```
#include <pthread.h>

void *func_b(void *args){
    return args;
}

void *func_a(void *args){
    pthread_t pth[5];
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        pthread_create(&pth[i], NULL, func_b, NULL);
    }

    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        pthread_join(pth[i], NULL);
    }
    return args;
}

int main(void){
    pthread_t pth[100];
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < 100; i++){
        pthread_create(&pth[i], NULL, func_a, NULL);
    }

    for(i = 0; i < 100; i++){
        pthread_join(pth[i], NULL);
    }
}
```

The full output from helgrind is [here](http://pastebin.com/UE92vG82) and all the relevant code is next. This snippet goes from line 171 to line 477.

```
void *read_record(void *_args){
    struct _thread_args *args = (struct _thread_args *)_args;
    uint32_t data_size = 0;

    args->item->record->type = calloc(5, sizeof *args->item->record->type);
    memcpy(args->item->record->type, *args->map, 4);
    *args->map += 4;
    memcpy(&data_size, *args->map, 4);
    *args->map += 4;
    memcpy(&args->item->record->flags, *args->map, 4);
    *args->map += 4;
    memcpy(&args->item->record->id, *args->map, 4);
    *args->map += 4;
    memcpy(&args->item->record->revision, *args->map, 4);
    *args->map += 4;
    memcpy(&args->item->record->version, *args->map, 2);
    *args->map += 2;
    memcpy(&args->item->record->unknown, *args->map, 2);
    *args->map += 2;

    args->item->record->misc_data = NULL;
    args->item->record->children = NULL;
    args->item->record->last = NULL;
    // args->item->record->next = NULL;
    // args->item->record->previous = NULL;
    args->item->record->_proxy = NULL;
    args->item->record->compression_level = 0x7f;  // some invalid number, doesn't matter

    if(args->parse_records){
        args->item->record->is_parsed = TRUE;
        if(args->item->record->flags & 0x00040000){
            uLongf uncompressed_size = 0;
            memcpy(&uncompressed_size, *args->map, 4);
            *args->map += 4;

            if(*(*args->map + 1) & (1 << 6)){
                if(*(*args->map + 1) & (1 << 7)){
                    args->item->record->compression_level = Z_BEST_COMPRESSION;  // both hight bits are set  11

                } else{
                    args->item->record->compression_level = Z_BEST_SPEED;  // 01
                }
            } else{
                if(*(*args->map + 1) & (1 << 7)){
                    args->item->record->compression_level = Z_DEFAULT_COMPRESSION;  // 10

                } else{
                    args->item->record->compression_level = Z_NO_COMPRESSION;  // 00
                }
            }

            uint8_t *uncompressed_data = malloc(uncompressed_size * sizeof *uncompressed_data);
            uint8_t *start = uncompressed_data;
            uncompress(uncompressed_data, &uncompressed_size, *args->map, data_size - 4);
            parse_record_data((uint8_t **)&uncompressed_data, uncompressed_size, &args->item->record->children, &args->item->record->last);
            *args->map += data_size - 4;
            free(start);
        } else{
            parse_record_data(args->map, data_size, &args->item->record->children, &args->item->record->last);
        }
    } else{
        args->item->record->is_parsed = FALSE;
        args->item->record->misc_data = malloc(sizeof *args->item->record->misc_data);
        args->item->record->misc_data->data = malloc(data_size * sizeof *args->item->record->misc_data->data);
        args->item->record->misc_data->data_size = data_size;
        memcpy(args->item->record->misc_data->data, *args->map, data_size);
        *args->map += data_size;
    }

    return NULL;
}

void *read_group(void *_args){
    struct _thread_args *args = (struct _thread_args *)_args;
    uint32_t data_size = 0;

    args->item->group->type = "GRUP";
    *args->map += 4;
    memcpy(&data_size, *args->map, 4);
    *args->map += 4;
    memset(args->item->group->label, 0, 5);
    memcpy(args->item->group->label, *args->map, 4);
    *args->map += 4;
    memcpy(&args->item->group->group_type, *args->map, 4);
    *args->map += 4;
    memcpy(&args->item->group->stamp, *args->map, 2);
    *args->map += 2;
    memcpy(&args->item->group->unknown1, *args->map, 2);
    *args->map += 2;
    memcpy(&args->item->group->version, *args->map, 2);
    *args->map += 2;
    memcpy(&args->item->group->unknown2, *args->map, 2);
    *args->map += 2;

    args->item->group->children = NULL;
    args->item->group->last = NULL;
    args->item->group->_proxy = NULL;

    uint8_t *data_start = *args->map;
    int item_count = 0;
    while(*args->map < (data_start + data_size - 24)){
        item_count++;
        char next_type[5] = {0};
        memcpy(next_type, *args->map, 4);
        uint32_t next_data_size = 0;
        memcpy(&next_data_size, *args->map + 4, 4);
        *args->map += next_data_size;
        if(strcmp(next_type, "GRUP") != 0){
            *args->map += 24;
        }
    }
    *args->map = data_start;

    pthread_attr_t  attrs;
    pthread_attr_init(&attrs);
    pthread_attr_setstacksize(&attrs, 1000);

    struct _group_item *current = NULL;
    bool current_is_record = FALSE;
    pthread_t *pth_array = malloc(item_count * sizeof *pth_array);
    uint8_t **map_array = malloc(item_count * sizeof *map_array);
    struct _thread_args *args_array = malloc(item_count * sizeof *args_array);
    int k;
    for(k = 0; k < item_count; k++){
        char next_type[5] = {0};
        memcpy(next_type, *args->map, 4);
        uint32_t new_data_size = 0;
        memcpy(&new_data_size, *args->map + 4, 4);
        *(map_array + k) = *args->map;
        *args->map += new_data_size;

        (*(args_array + k)).map = map_array + k;
        (*(args_array + k)).parse_records = args->parse_records;
        (*(args_array + k)).item = malloc(sizeof *(*(args_array + k)).item);
        if(strcmp(next_type, "GRUP") == 0){
            (*(args_array + k)).is_record = FALSE;
            (*(args_array + k)).item->group = malloc(sizeof *(*(args_array + k)).item->group);
            pthread_create(pth_array + k, &attrs, read_group, args_array + k);
            //read_group(args_array + k);
        } else{
            *args->map += 24;
            (*(args_array + k)).is_record = TRUE;
            (*(args_array + k)).item->record = malloc(sizeof *(*(args_array + k)).item->record);
            pthread_create(pth_array + k, &attrs, read_record, args_array + k);
            //read_record(args_array + k);
        }

        if(args->item->group->children == NULL){
            args->item->group->children = current = (*(args_array + k)).item;
            args->item->group->children_is_record = current_is_record = (*(args_array + k)).is_record;
            if((*(args_array + k)).is_record){
                current->record->previous = NULL;
            } else{
                current->group->previous = NULL;
            }
            continue;
        }

        if((*(args_array + k)).is_record){
            if(current_is_record){
                current->record->next = (*(args_array + k)).item;
                current->record->next_is_record = (*(args_array + k)).is_record;
                (*(args_array + k)).item->record->previous = current;
                (*(args_array + k)).item->record->previous_is_record = current_is_record;
            } else{
                current->group->next = (*(args_array + k)).item;
                current->group->next_is_record = (*(args_array + k)).is_record;
                (*(args_array + k)).item->record->previous = current;
                (*(args_array + k)).item->record->previous_is_record = current_is_record;
            }
        } else{
            if(current_is_record){
                current->record->next = (*(args_array + k)).item;
                current->record->next_is_record = (*(args_array + k)).is_record;
                (*(args_array + k)).item->group->previous = current;
                (*(args_array + k)).item->group->previous_is_record = current_is_record;
            } else{
                current->group->next = (*(args_array + k)).item;
                current->group->next_is_record = (*(args_array + k)).is_record;
                (*(args_array + k)).item->group->previous = current;
                (*(args_array + k)).item->group->previous_is_record = current_is_record;
            }
        }

        current = (*(args_array + k)).item;
        current_is_record = (*(args_array + k)).is_record;
    }

    args->item->group->last = current;
    args->item->group->last_is_record = current_is_record;
    if(current != NULL){
        if(current_is_record){
            current->record->next = NULL;
        } else{
            current->group->next = NULL;
        }
    }

    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < item_count; i++){
       pthread_join(*(pth_array + i), NULL);
    }

    free(pth_array);
    free(map_array);
    free(args_array);

    assert(*args->map == (data_start + data_size - 24));
    return NULL;
}

Plugin *plugin_read(const char *filename, const bool parse_records){
    Plugin *plugin = malloc(sizeof *plugin);
    plugin->children = NULL;
    plugin->last = NULL;
    plugin->_proxy = NULL;

    FILE *fileobject = fopen(filename, "rb");
    if(fileobject == NULL){
        printf("No file found.\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    fseek(fileobject, 0, SEEK_END);
    long int filesize = ftell(fileobject);
    rewind(fileobject);
    uint8_t *map = malloc(filesize * sizeof *map);
    fread(map, filesize, 1, fileobject);
    fclose(fileobject);

    uint8_t *start = map;

    pthread_attr_t  attrs;
    pthread_attr_init(&attrs);
    pthread_attr_setstacksize(&attrs, 1000);

    pthread_t header_pth;
    plugin->header = malloc(sizeof *plugin->header);
    struct _group_item header_item;
    header_item.record = plugin->header;
    uint8_t *header_map = map;
    struct _thread_args header_args;
    header_args.item = &header_item;
    header_args.map = &header_map;
    header_args.parse_records = parse_records;
    pthread_create(&header_pth, &attrs, read_record, &header_args);
    uint32_t header_data_size = 0;
    memcpy(&header_data_size, map + 4, 4);
    map += header_data_size + 24;

    uint8_t *after_header = map;
    int group_count = 0;
    while(map < (start + filesize)){
        group_count++;
        uint32_t next_data_size = 0;
        memcpy(&next_data_size, map + 4, 4);
        map += next_data_size;
    }
    map = after_header;

    pthread_t *pth = malloc(group_count * sizeof *pth);
    uint8_t **map_array = malloc(group_count * sizeof *map_array);
    struct _thread_args *args = malloc(group_count * sizeof *args);
    struct _group_item *current = NULL;
    int k;
    for(k = 0; k < group_count; k++){
        uint32_t new_data_size = 0;
        memcpy(&new_data_size, map + 4, 4);
        *(map_array + k) = map;
        map += new_data_size;

        (*(args + k)).item = malloc(sizeof *(*(args + k)).item);
        (*(args + k)).item->group = malloc(sizeof *(*(args + k)).item->group);
        (*(args + k)).map = map_array + k;
        (*(args + k)).parse_records = parse_records;
        pthread_create(pth + k, &attrs, read_group, args + k);

        if(plugin->children == NULL){
            plugin->children = (*(args + k)).item;
            current = (*(args + k)).item;
            current->group->previous = NULL;
            continue;
        }

        current->group->next = (*(args + k)).item;
        current->group->next_is_record = FALSE;
        (*(args + k)).item->group->previous = current;
        (*(args + k)).item->group->previous_is_record = FALSE;
        current = (*(args + k)).item;
    }
    plugin->last = current;
    plugin->last->group->next = NULL;

    pthread_join(header_pth, NULL);
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < group_count; i++){
        pthread_join(*(pth + i), NULL);
    }

    assert(map == (start + filesize));

    free(start);
    free(pth);
    free(args);
    free(map_array);

    return plugin;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Post the code here. And please create a minimal example that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Done! Thanks for the advice :)

Comment: Apart from not checking the return values the minimal example looks correct. Maybe you created too many threads, didn't check the return value when pthread function failed, and caused undefined behavior.

Comment: I later tried with the number of threads in the minimal example at two on the main loop. I've managed to run over a hundred threads on this system, why is it locking up at 10? Just added a little if statement to check for return values and they're all 0.

Comment: Your minimal example looks right to me. What race condition are you encountering in your minimal example?

Comment: The "type" of errors are exactly the same as the ones at the top of the question, here: http://pastebin.com/dAzFmyF0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try --sim-hints=no-nptl-pthread-stackcache.

See http://www.valgrind.org/docs/manual/manual-core.html#manual-core.rareopts for more information.

Comment: +1: This false-positive hypothesis seems plausible, because there appears nothing wrong with the minimal repro test case.

Comment: Thanks! With this out of the way I managed to figure out what was truly wrong with my methods :D

Comment: Be curious if anyone can chime in and say if they saw/resolved this issue on ARM, and if valgrind uses the correct smc-check? Unlike all the other examples on stackoverflow, my highest level frame is just the allocate_stack (allocatestack.c:561) call. So I'm guessing a false positive.